# Non-negative uniformly integrable local martingale

Tags: martingales, uniform-integrability, local-martingales

I am not sure if the following is true or not:

"A non-negative uniformly integrable continuous local martingale is a (true) martingale."

Is this statement true? Or can someone give a counter-example?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question in a previous answer to a different question I got:
[Uniformly integrable local martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860287/uniformly-integrable-local-martingale)

The answer is no.